# Games do not work with a Nvidia GT 555M on Asus N55SF

Tags: technical-issues, graphics-card

When I start games (ex: PES 2012) a warning message appears:

> Your computer does not meet the minimum specifications necessary to
>   run this software. You may experience errors during operation. The
>   video card does not have the necessary specifications.(GPU:VRAM
>   128MB)"

---

I have tried many things, such as:

- Updating my Nvidia driver with the newest version 268.74
- Forcing the application to open using "Run with graphic processor" and adding the game in the application within the Nvidia control panel

However, the game still does not work.

[image: Error Message]

> System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.  System Model: N55SF
>   Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
>   Memory: 8192MB RAM  DirectX Version: DirectX 11  Diplay : Intel(R) HD
>   Graphics Family + nvidia Geforce GT 555M with Optimus Techhnology

Comment: Well it _is_ a mobile card so it is possible that the game will not support it.  The mobile versions are _not_ equivalent performance-wise (and in all other respects) to the desktop versions.

Comment: It could be that the card has too much video RAM. According to the manufacturer's website, you should have 2 GiB of video RAM. Some older applications may not detect that correctly. Also are you sure that the switch from Intel adapter to nVidia one is working correctly? Check BIOS options and see if it's possible to somehow disable temporarily Optimus and make the system use the nVidia card only and see if that helps. Also what happens when you click ignore? What other games make such error? Does any game work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I took time to read on their website the requirement...

I also chekd the following website they say that it should be working with your computer :

[Game-Debate Website that gives you a chance to check if your PC is good enough for it](http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=1401&game=Pro%20Evolution%20Soccer%202012)

But if I read properly it's minimum requirement 128 of RAM... Yours is sadly VRAM so it's possible that the game don't want to load cause it's not an actual 128 real ram

VRAM means that it's shared with your Computer Memory and not it's own Memory.

If it's a legit game I could try to contact them directly, their might be a mistake in coding that doesn't allow VRAM or it litteraly DOESN'T allow 128 VRAM.

Comment: Any sources for `VRAM means that it's shared with your Computer Memory and not it's own Memory.`?? It's the first time I heard something similar.

Comment: That is totally weird, the 555M is supposed to have 1gb dedicated ddr3 or gddr3 ram as its a rather good mobile video card